# noUISlider -- `Uncaught Error: Slider was already initialized`

Tags: javascript, nouislider

This question has been asked before and I've tried the posted solutions, however I am still unable to resolve and hoping someone might be able to help me.

I have a single noUISlider on a webpage that is used to apply a filter to a dataset. After submitting the values, the page is reloaded with updated results from the backend. When this happens, the noUISlider no longer appears on the page anymore.

As suggested in other posts, I added a conditional to check if the slider object is defined and then used 'slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions (options,true)' when the slider is already initialized. However, the slider does not appear in the UI and the slider div is not populated.

Can anyone help me? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've also tried destroying the slider if it exists and then recreating it -- but the same thing happens.

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

var slider_options = {start: [0,100],connect: true,step: 1,behaviour: 'drag',range:{'min': 0, 'max': 100}};

// If the slider doesn't exist, then create it

    if (typeof slider.noUiSlider === "undefined") {
       noUiSlider.create(slider,slider_options);
    }

// If the slider already exists, then update the options with TRUE parameter

    else {
       slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions(slider_options,true);
    }
```

Comment: There isn't enough code in your question to pinpoint the problem here. Are there perhaps multiple elements with the `slider` id in the DOM?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. There is only one div with the slider and only one div that has id = "slider". Everything works great when the page initially loads. But, when the same page is refreshed, the slider element is no longer present. I also tried adding a delay, just in case it was a timing issue -- but that didn't help either. Thanks again for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: I think you should provide more code to make it easier to understand.